# Vector norm and relationship with euclidean distance

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If $y\in E_n$ (n dimensional euclidean space) show that $||\textbf{y}||\leq|\textbf{y}|\leq \sqrt{n}||\textbf{y}||$

Where $||\textbf{y}||$ is the euclidean length of the vector $\textbf{y}$

and $|\textbf{y}|$ is the norm of $\textbf{y}$

The hint: Use the inequality $2|uv|\leq |u|^2+|v|^2$

to show

$||\textbf{y}||^2\leq|\textbf{y}|^2\leq n||\textbf{y}||^2$

By letting $u=|y|$ and $v=y$ I get

$2||y|y|\leq||y||^2+|y|^2$ I don't really see how this helps.

[image: norms]

Comment: But what is the norm $|\bf y|$?

Comment: which norm do you mean by $| \cdot |$, if $|| \cdot ||$ is the 2-norm (euclidean norm)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...I added the picture to show what norms are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=(y_1,...,y_n).$ $$\text { We have }\quad |y|^2-\|y\|^2=[\;\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|\;]^2-\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}2|y_i|.|y_j|\geq 0.$$  $$\text  { We have }\quad 0\leq \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(y_i-y_j)^2=(n-1)\sum_{i-1}^ny_i^2-2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}y_iy_j=$$ $$=n\|y\|^2-\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}y_iy_j=n\|y\|^2-|y|^2.$$

Comment: I'm a little unsure about the second inequality. I've written it out expanded as (y_1-y_2)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2+...+(y_i-y_j)^2 is this how I should interpret it?

Comment: Yes. Expand.Example :$ (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=2(a^2+b^2+c^2)-2(a b+ b c+c a)=$ $=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a^2 +b^2 +c^2 +2 a b+2 b c+2 c a)$ $=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a+b+c)^2.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** for any nonnegative number $a$ and $b$ you have
$$
(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\ge a^2+b^2
$$
and
$$
2(a^2+b^2)-(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2\ge0.
$$
Hence,
$$
a+b\ge\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\quad\text{and}\quad \sqrt2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\ge a+b.
$$